# Angularjs Table Route

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, router

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.0-rc3-nonmin" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ng-table@*" data-semver="0.3.0" src="http://bazalt-cms.com/assets/ng-table/0.3.0/ng-table.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ng-table-export@0.1.0" data-semver="0.1.0" src="http://bazalt-cms.com/assets/ng-table-export/0.1.0/ng-table-export.js"></script>
    <link data-require="ng-table@*" data-semver="0.3.0" rel="stylesheet" href="http://bazalt-cms.com/assets/ng-table/0.3.0/ng-table.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="main" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
      <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
        <td data-title="'Name'">
          <span ng-if="!user.$edit">{{user.name}}</span>
          <div ng-if="user.$edit"><input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="user.name" /></div>
        </td>
        <td data-title="'Age'" width="200">
          <span ng-if="!user.$edit">{{user.age}}</span>
          <div ng-if="user.$edit"><input class="form-control" type="number" ng-model="user.age" /></div>
        </td>
        <td data-title="'Actions'" width="200">
          <a ng-if="!user.$edit" href="" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="user.$edit = true">Edit</a>
          <a ng-if="user.$edit" href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="user.$edit = false">Save</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have this simple example..it works.
but when I wanted to do any like this

```js
var App = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute']).controller('tableController', function ($scope, ngTableParams, $sce) {
    $scope.data = [{ name: "Moroni", age: 50 },
        { name: "Tiancum", age: 43 },
        { name: "Jacob", age: 27 },
        { name: "Nephi", age: 29 },
        { name: "Enos", age: 34 },
        { name: "Tiancum", age: 43 },
        { name: "Jacob", age: 27 },
        { name: "Nephi", age: 29 },
        { name: "Enos", age: 34 },
        { name: "Tiancum", age: 43 },
        { name: "Jacob", age: 27 },
        { name: "Nephi", age: 29 },
        { name: "Enos", age: 34 },
        { name: "Tiancum", age: 43 },
        { name: "Jacob", age: 27 },
        { name: "Nephi", age: 29 },
        { name: "Enos", age: 34 }];
    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10           // count per page
    }, {
            total: $scope.data.length, // length of data
            getData: function ($defer, params) {
                $defer.resolve($scope.data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
            }
        });
    App.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                controller: function ($scope) {
                }
            })
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl: 'about.html',
                controller: 'tableController'
            });
    });
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="App">
<head>
   <!-- SCROLLS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <!-- SPELLS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ng-table@*" data-semver="0.3.0" src="http://bazalt-cms.com/assets/ng-table/0.3.0/ng-table.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ng-table-export@0.1.0" data-semver="0.1.0" src="http://bazalt-cms.com/assets/ng-table-export/0.1.0/ng-table-export.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular-route.min.js"></script>.
    <link data-require="ng-table@*" data-semver="0.3.0" rel="stylesheet" href="http://bazalt-cms.com/assets/ng-table/0.3.0/ng-table.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/"> home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about"> about</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

something go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you aren't loading ngRoute, and you have syntax errors in your javascript.

As well, you've got your ng table scripts loading BEFORE your angular scripts.

Comment: I add angular-route.min.js, but it doesn't work..
can you see again? I understand, that it's simple.

Comment: You still haven't fixed the syntax errors. Copy paste what's in-between your <script> tags into a javascript validator and you'll see that you have more opening braces than you do closed braces.

Comment: I've fixed it. it doesn't work...